# this not of type CombinedVueInstance in vue with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

On most components, when using `this` inside for example a method on my vue object, it gets type `CombinedVueInstance`, which is how it should be. But sometimes, it gets types like `Vue` when accessing `this` in a method and `Accessors<DefaultComputed>` when accessing `this` in a computed method, even though nothing seems to be different. This is what the code looks like:

```
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    field: Object as PropType<FieldType>,
    row: Boolean as PropType<boolean>,
    events: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: undefined,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    required() {
      return this.field.required && !this.value
    },
    invalid() {
      return this.field.isValid && !this.field.isValid(this.value)
    }
  },
```

Why does `this` sometimes not get type `CombinedVueInstance` when used inside the Vue component object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give your computed properties explicit return values. (It often removes the error: *this not of type CombinedVueInstance in vue with typescript*)

```
computed: {
    required(): boolean {
      return this.field.required && !this.value
    },
    invalid(): boolean {
      return this.field.isValid && !this.field.isValid(this.value)
    }
  },
```

Comment: Good advice I'm sure but this doesn't answer OP's question at all

Comment: Often I get that exact 'error' and it goes away when I add the return values, so, yes, it does answer the question.

Comment: Interesting. I can't see how exactly but if this works for OP, fantastic

Comment: There is most likely a bug in the parser when it calculates implicit return values.  I can state with confidence that adding the return type removes that error many times for me.

Comment: Adding explicit return values to the computed properties actually solved it, thank you!

Comment: And there you go @Phil, another happy customer.

Comment: How about that. I'll have to bookmark this one for when I eventually make the same mistake 

Comment: It's not really a mistake.  OP should not have to do it, so I would call it a workaround that also follows best practice.